# gcc C/C++ assume no pointer aliasing

Tags: pointers, gcc, pointer-aliasing

Having recently read that the main reason why fortran is faster than c/c++ in numerical computations is because there is no pointer aliasing.

Apparently, using `restrict` or `__restrict__` keywords allows on a case by case basis to indicate the absence of pointer aliasing for a given memory element.

The icc compiler apparently has an option `-fno-alias` which allows one to globally assume that no aliasing is present. On gcc there is `-fno-strict-aliasing`, which applies only to a subset of all the aliasing situations.

Is there an option present in gcc, or are there some cases where no aliasing is assumed, when using certain optimization flags?

Comment: Regarding GCC's `-fno-strict-aliasing`, you have it backwards. The option cause the compiler to worry that some aliases may exist. By default, it assumes that these aliases do not exist.

Comment: The cases where the `restrict` keyword matters are pretty rare actually, and it is usually pretty obvious where it matters. [This document](http://cellperformance.beyond3d.com/articles/2006/05/demystifying-the-restrict-keyword.html) is quite informative, and emphasizes the fact that the order of loads and stores matter too. But as I said before, the cases where you will use such optimization are quite obvious to spot.

Comment: I don't think `GCC` has anything similar to [Intel's option `-fno-alias`](https://software.intel.com/en-us/cpp-compiler-developer-guide-and-reference-falias-oa) (Which basically is equivalent of annotating each pointer by the `restrict` annotation). I actually wish it did.

Comment: The compiler cannot vectorize an array loop if aliasing cannot be ruled out. __restrict is often necessary for vectorizing array loops.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

GCC has the option `-fstrict-aliasing` which enables aliasing optimizations globally and expects *you* to ensure that nothing gets illegally aliased. This optimization is enabled for `-O2` and `-O3` I believe.

C++ has well defined aliasing rules, though, and standard-compliant code will not conflict with strict aliasing. In particular this means you're not allowed to access one variable through a pointer to a different type:

```
float f;
int * p = reinterpret_cast<int*>(&f);  // uh-oh
*p = 0x3FF00000;                       // breaks strict aliasing
```

The crucial exception to this rule is that you can always access any variable through a pointer to `char`. (This is necessary for serializing through IO operations.)

The aliasing rules do not help the compiler to know whether any pointers of the same type alias each other. Consider this:

```
void add(float * a, float * b, float * c) { *c = *a + *b; }
```

Here the compiler cannot know whether `c` points to different memory than `a` or `b` and has to be careful. I think this is where `restrict` makes a difference, essentially by promising that `float * restrict c` means that nobody aliases `c`.

Comment: I think your analysis is right: this is exactly the kinds of spots `restrict` was introduced for. See also http://cellperformance.beyond3d.com/articles/2006/05/demystifying-the-restrict-keyword.html for additional details, including how to write a function using `restrict` pointers to hint the compiler about how to schedule loads and stores.

Comment: This answer is very instructive but does not answer the question. I have a hard time believing there is no equivalent to -fnoalias other than manually adding "restrict" everywhere in your application

Comment: I think the OP was talking about aliasing of 2 different pointers pointing to the same address which is a case which prevents optimization. While GCC flag is about alising of types, not addresses. Unless I read the documentation wrong.